# Spark Streaming Receiver shows “negative number” in the "Records in last batch"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, receiver

I met the following issue in the Spark Streaming receivers. The UI portal shows the negative number in the "Records in last batch". What does this mean? Does this mean, the last batch data did not finish the processsing?

Pipeline Detail: **Custom receiver** on **Spark 1.2.1 & Scala 2.10.4**

[image: Spark Streaming Receiver shows the negative numbers]

Following is the code in the receiver: (A little complex with Azure SDK and Microsoft Bond)

```
class AriaQueueDataReceiver(storageConnectionString: String, queueName: String, blobContainerName: String, threadCount: Int) extends Receiver[BondSerializableWrapper[EventEnvelope]](StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) {

  override def onStart(): Unit = {
    // start mutliple threads to receive data to maximize IO usage
    for(i <- 0 until threadCount) {
      new Thread(s"AriaQueueDataReceiver[$i]") {
        override def run() {
          receive()
        }
      }.start()
    }
  }

  override def onStop(): Unit = {
  }

  def commit(envelopes: Iterable[EventEnvelope]): Boolean = {
    try {
      val wrappers = envelopes.map(e => new BondSerializableWrapper[EventEnvelope](e, classOf[EventEnvelope]))
      store(wrappers.iterator)
      true
    }
    catch {
      case e: Throwable =>
        false
    }
  }

  def processQueueMessage(queueMessage: CloudQueueMessage, queue: CloudQueue, blobContainer: CloudBlobContainer): Unit = {
    // read the queue message content
    val queueMessageBytes = queueMessage.getMessageContentAsByte

    if (queueMessageBytes != null) {
      // blob location in the queue message points to the actual data blob
      val blobLocation = AriaDataDeserializationUtils.getBlobLocation(queueMessageBytes)

      if (blobLocation != null) {
        val correctedBlobLocation = if (blobLocation.startsWith(blobContainer.getUri.toString)) blobLocation.substring(blobContainer.getUri.toString.length + 1) else blobLocation

        // download and read the data blob
        val blob = blobContainer.getBlockBlobReference(correctedBlobLocation)

        if (blob.exists()) {
          val bufferStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
          blob.download(bufferStream)
          val blobContent = bufferStream.toByteArray
          bufferStream.close()

          // deserialize the data blob into DataPackage objects
          val exceptionBuffer = new ArrayBuffer[Throwable]
          val dataPackages = AriaDataDeserializationUtils.deserializeDataPackages(blobContent, exceptionBuffer)

          // DataPackage is the schema used inside ARIA while our pipeline is supposed to deal with EventEnvelope schema.
          // here we convert DataPackage objects into EventEnvelope objects so that our pipeline logic will only deal with EventEnvelopes.
          val events = AriaDataDeserializationUtils.convertDataPackagesToEventEnvelopes(dataPackages)

          // try to commit the EventEnvelope objects into Spark Streaming.
          // if the commit failed, simply does nothing and the queue message will reappear in the queue in a fixed time period.
          if (commit(events)) {
            queue.deleteMessage(queueMessage)
            blob.delete()
          }

          // commit the exceptions as well so that the data pipeline can choose to handle the errors
          val exceptionWrappers = exceptionBuffer.map(e => {
            val wrapper = new BondSerializableWrapper[EventEnvelope](null, classOf[EventEnvelope])
            wrapper.setException(e)
            wrapper
          })

          store(exceptionWrappers.iterator)
        }
        else {
          queue.deleteMessage(queueMessage)

          val wrapper = new BondSerializableWrapper[EventEnvelope](null, classOf[EventEnvelope])
          wrapper.setException(new InternalError(s"Blob could not be found"))

          store(wrapper)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def receive(): Unit = {
    // initialize azure storage client
    val storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString)
    val queueClient = storageAccount.createCloudQueueClient()
    val queue = queueClient.getQueueReference(queueName)

    val blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient()
    val blobContainer = blobClient.getContainerReference(blobContainerName)

    while(!isStopped()) {
      try {
        for (queueMessage <- queue.retrieveMessages(32)) {
          processQueueMessage(queueMessage, queue, blobContainer)
        }
      }
      catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          // any uncaught exception during queue message processing will be stored as well
          // so that the data pipeline can choose to handle the errors
          val wrapper = new BondSerializableWrapper[EventEnvelope](null, classOf[EventEnvelope])
          wrapper.setException(e)
          store(wrapper)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks,

-Tao

Comment: That's very odd. Smells like a bug. Which receiver are you using?  I think this should be reported to the Spark Mailing list. If you are not a subscriber, I could proxy that for you. /cc @TathagataDas

Comment: pls, also specify your Spark version, scala version and add the code of your streaming job is possible.

Comment: Thanks @maasg for your response. The receiver is a custom receiver on Spark 1.2.1 & Scala 2.10.4

Comment: In the case of a custom receiver, could you add the code of the receiver as well as the job to the question (use "edit")?

Comment: Also, the following setting does not work in the receiver.

      .set("spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate", "50")
      .set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")